# Как можно написать код который скопирует n первых букв стринга без использования strncpy?

Tags: c

Помогите пожалуйста как можно написать код в Си который скопирует определенное количество букв первого стринга и как бы используя эти буквы создаст новый стринг? Как функция strncpy, только без ее использования? Заранее спасибо большое

Comment: Можете посмотреть на один из вариантов сорсов [strncpy](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/strncpy.c) (она вызывает [stpncpy](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/string/stpncpy.c),  а вот вызов memset() в ее конце, скорее всего вам не нужен)

Answer (score 1):

Знаете чем прекрасно [открытое программное обеспечение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)? Тем что есть доступ к исходному коду. В том числе к [исходному коду функции strndup](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strndup.c.html) в стандартной библиотеке языка С. Хотя этот код имеет особенности связанные с его "библиотечностью" и использует нестандартные функции вроде `strnlen`, идею понять легко.

На "человеческом" C получится что-то вроде такого: отмеряем сколько байт копировать, выделяем буфер на единицу большего размера, копируем, добавляем ноль:

```
char *dup_n(const char *s, size_t n) {
    // сколько байт будем копировать?
    const size_t len = strlen(s);
    const size_t m = (n <= len) ? n : len;

    // выделяем новую строку, не забываем место под завершающий ноль
    char *dup = malloc(m + 1);

    // обработка нехватки памяти
    if (dup != NULL) {
        // копируем нужое число байтов
        memcpy(dup, s, m);

        // завершаем новую строку нулем
        dup[m] = '\0';
    }

    // готово
    return dup;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как то так

n - нужное кол-во символов
str - исходная строка

```
int len = strlen(str);
if (n > len) n = len;
char* new_string = malloc(n+1);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   new_string[i] = str[i];
}
new_string[n] = '\0';
```

Comment: добавлю, что если не делать `strndup()` вместо `strncpy()`, то предварительно вызывать `strlen()` не нужно...

Comment: пытался переварить этот комментарий, но не могу. А его даже провотапили. где тут strndup...

Comment: дык, `strdup` копирует указанную строку в новую с выделением памяти под неё с помощью `malloc()`: это ровно то, что ты делаешь... а `strncpy` должен копировать строку в заранее выделенный буфер и в этом случае предварительный вызов `strlen()` был бы расточительным излишеством...

Comment: и где у меня strdup? я понял автора вопроса буквально (как это бывает в домашних заданиях) - написать прямолинейно. Может это не мне комментарий? очень похоже на то

Comment: ты же буквально расписал реализацию `new_string = strndup(str, n);`... я не возьмусь доподлинно утверждать, что именно автор хотел сказать своим вопросом, но в нём упоминается `strncpy()`, а в её эффективной реализации (в отличии от `strndup()`) не должно быть лишнего вызова `strlen()`... об этом собственно и замечание...

Comment: Я думаю, *Вы* говорите с кем то другим.

Comment: Нум... взаимно...